# flutter : Checkbox

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dart-null-safety

```dart
Checkbox(
    value: good,
    onChanged: (val) {
      setState(() {
        good = val;
      });
    }),
```

There is a red line under the val `good = val`, what is the reason?

I didn't forget to write above    `bool good = false;`

Comment: what exactly your problem is?

Comment: Someone answered me, I forgot to write ( ??false;)

Answer (score 2):

`onChanged` provide nullable `bool`, define as

```
{required void Function(bool?)? onChanged}
```

you can provide false on null case like

```dart
onChanged: (val) {
  setState(() {
    good = val??false;
  });
}
```

Find more about [null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)

Comment: thanks Problem solved. I wrote good=val??false and now it's working thank you yeasin <3

Comment: Glad to help, you can explore the link to find more about null-safety

Answer (score 1):

```
    onChanged: (val) {
      setState(() {
         good = !good; 
      });
    }
```

> With this you can use switch good value from true to false or false to true every time you trigger this function